# Specify linker on the command line

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have such a cargo config:

```
[target.x86_64h-apple-darwin]
linker = "x86_64-apple-darwin14-clang"
ar = "x86_64-apple-darwin14-ar"
```

Please tell me how I can transfer these parameters to the command line.

```
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std <THESE PARAMS> --target x86_64h-apple-darwin
```

`<THESE PARAMS>` - here I somehow need to specify linker and ar.

All this in order to assemble the std for x86_64**h**-apple-darwin in my script...

Or maybe this can be done somehow using environment variables?..

Comment: Would you be OK with having these parameters in the environment instead? `env CARGO_TARGET_X86_64H_APPLE_DARWIN_LINKER=x86_64-apple-darwin14-clang cargo +nightly build …` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
MACOS_TARGET="x86_64-apple-darwin"
cargo build --config "target.${MACOS_TARGET}.ar = 'x86_64-apple-darwin14-ar'" --config "target.${MACOS_TARGET}.linker = 'x86_64-apple-darwin14-clang'" --config "profile.release.strip = false"  ...
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#command-line-overrides